# Zend e-commerce extension

Tags: magento, zend-framework

If I build a site with Zend framework, and later want to add an e-commerce extension, can I esaily plug Magento? Do have I to rebuild the website from a fresh new magento install?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and what research did you do?

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily have to rebuild the whole website. If you have a lot of CMS pages you would probably keep those and install Magento in order to provide the e-commerce functionality. Although Magento is based on Zend Framework it has its own template system, so I guess you would have to rebuild your theme with the Magento template system.

Answer (score 1):

The Zend framework from Magento is a little bit different of the official one. The `Require(...);` files are commented. It means that your web application must implement the autoloader of ZF. Additionally you have to pay attention of the ZF version that you use with Magento and your app, it's not always the last version